# Why it takes time to change DNS server on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

When I try to change the DNS server manually from my network interface configurations on windows 7 as below:

[image]
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cght.jpg)

To some random host that does not provide DNS service (any invalid IP ) it takes some time (about 30 seconds) till my browser can't reach any site,

**Why it takes this time? Isn't changing the DNS this way suppose to corrupt the network immediately ?**

Comment: It seems I misunderstood your question. I was going to remove it, but there's a conversation going on, so I'll keep it alive.

Comment: Are you (re)trying recently visited sites? Any DNS entries already in cache will remain there and continue to be used until their Time To Live expires; TTL is set by the zone owner and varies, but a minute or a few minutes is common and more than an hour is rare. `ipconfig /displaydns` shows the current contents.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior.

Your browser tries to contact the dns server. Because it does not exists, it tries and tries and tries until it times out. The default time-out time is 30 seconds. If you want to get an immediate response, make it resolve to an address that exists but does not provide a DNS service, such as localhost (127.0.0.1)

Comment: No, my browser can reach correct sites during this 30 seconds, then it falls,  is this suppose to happen? , thank you for your help

Comment: DNS is UDP. Even if the host exists but doesn't provide DNS services doesn't mean you'd immediately get an error response. You'd still be waiting since there is no response, just like with a non-existent host.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by LPChip, this is normal, the DNS change should take effect immediately, but this is your browser doing its own thing. It will make a request to the nameserver, and then only request the page from the server once the destination is known.

It will try for up to 30 seconds, continually sending the UDP packet requesting information from the DNS server. After 30s with no response, the browser should error our. You will have seen one of the following messages from chrome:

> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Would be your browser receiving a valid response from a nameserver, but the nameserver responded saying it did not have information available for that record.

> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

Would be that the nameserver never sends a response back.

> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Would be received if you had resolved a domain name to an ip, but the request packet to that ip was not responded to

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Would be received if you had resolved a domain name to an ip, but the server at that ip refused your request.

In your scenario, I expect you to have received the second.